# What we have to do if in-app-purchase is successfully completed but what if user-form-data not submitted to server in ios?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, ios8, in-app-purchase

We are developing an app which has an in-app-purchase functionality in it where we need to send user email to our server once payment is success.Now my doubt is,after successful completion of in-app-purchase if the user-form-data(i.e user data like email) is not submitted to server or  request fails because of internet failure or power failure or may be other reason what i have to do?How should i handle this situation?

Please find below link for detailed explanation of my scenario:

http://hashcrush.com/images/FORM.png

Comment: What "user-form-data" are you talking about?

Comment: @trojanfoe it's user data and payment success status